# Jquery > retrieve a variable from a function... in a 'span'

Tags: jquery, function, variables, resize

I would like to retrieve the variable `new_width` which is calculated in the function, and to be able to send it in the `span`. I ABSOLUTELY do NOT want to put the `span` in the function. Here is my code, but it does not work. What's wrong ? Thanks. Nico.

```js
var new_width;

$(window).on('load resize', function() {

  W = $(window).width();
  new_width = W / 5;

  $("div").css("width", new_width);
});

$("span").html(new_width);
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
}

span {}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<span></span>
```

Comment: `new_width` only gets set after the load/resize event happens.  The setting of the span only happens on page load.  I don't understand your negativity toward setting the span inside the event handler, as until that point, you do not have the value to set.

Comment: `I ABSOLUTELY do NOT want to put the span in the function` why? You have no other option..

Comment: In fact, my function is much more complex than that. I need to bring out this variable because it will serve me for another function. I wanted to simplify the code for Stackoverflow. Nico.

Answer (score 0):

I've founded the solution :

```
$(window).on('load resize', function () {

    W = $(window).width();  
    new_width = W/5;

    $("div").css("width", new_width);
    get_value();

});

function get_value () {

    $("span").html(new_width);

}
```

That's all.. :-) Nico.

Comment: So you're using a global variable that can easily be overwritten? That seems unwise, why not simply define a named function with a get and set method? Or retrieve the variable from the `$('div').css('width')` (that you set)?

Comment: Yes, but the only way to retrieve the variable based on "load/resize-function", is to place the "span.html()" inside the "load/resize" function. But that, I do not want it. I want to be able to re-use this variable outside the "load/resize" function. Otherwise, I do not know how the "get/set method" works. I will watch. Thanks.